# Understanding the thought process behind describing $\sigma$-algebras generated by certain sets (and proving such descriptions)

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

I'm struggling to understand the intuition, as well as how to prove, that $\sigma$-algebras follow a certain form.

For example, let's consider the following: consider a set $X$, $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ denoted $\mathcal{A}$, and a set $B \subset X$.

Suppose I wanted to figure out what $\sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\})$ is. We define $\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\}$ to be the set of all sets $A \cap B$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

I do understand that $$\sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\}) = \bigcap_{\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\} \subset \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\text{, } \mathcal{A}^{\prime}\text{ a } \sigma\text{-algebra}}\mathcal{A}^{\prime}$$
but I don't find this definition particularly helpful for explicitly finding the form of such a collection of sets.

---

### A first attempt at intuition

For brevity, denote $S = \sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\})$.

Well, I know for a fact that $\varnothing \in S$, and that $S$ must be closed under complements and countable unions.

Other than the fact that I should expect to see sets in the form $A \cap B$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ in $S$, I should also expect to see sets of the form $(A \cap B)^c$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n \cap B)$ in $S$ as well, for $A, A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$.

We also know that $S$ would be closed under countable (and therefore finite) unions, so one would expect that $A \cup B \in S$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ as well, as well as countable unions of unions.

Given, my guess is that $\sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\})$ could be described by the following:
$$\{A \cap B, A \cup B: A \in \mathcal{A}\}$$
but I'm not $100\%$ sure.

---

### Attempting a proof?

So I have this set $T = \{A \cap B, A \cup B: A \in \mathcal{A}\}$. How would I prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \{B\})$ is equal to such?

Well, obviously $\varnothing \in T$ since $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\varnothing \cap B = \varnothing$ for any $B \subset X$.

The other properties I'm stuck on, probably because my description of $T$ is either inaccurate or insufficient.

---

Any help understanding the above would be appreciated. I can't find any such exposition in measure theory texts.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  What do you understand $\mathcal A \cap\{B\}$ to be?  The collection of all sets of form $A\cap B$ for $A\in \mathcal A$? Or the intersection of the collection of sets $A\in\mathcal A$ with the "collection" consisting of  the single set $B$?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: Which of the two are you talking about?

Comment: @kimchilover Oh, I see what you're saying. Let me think about this for a sec.

Comment: @kimchilover Retracting my old comment. I think it's the former. Collection of all sets $A \cap B$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: First note that $\mathcal{C} = \{ A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ (called the trace of $\mathcal{A}$). Now, every $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ containing $\mathcal{C}$ must also contain the complements of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$, so $$\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap \{B\}) \supseteq \mathcal{C}\cup \{ X \setminus C : C \in \mathcal{C}\}\,.$$ Then check whether the right hand side is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead
$$T = \{A \cap B, A \cup B^c : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$$

---

To prove $T \supseteq \sigma(\{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\})$, it suffices to show that $T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the sets in $\{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$, since then it would be one of the $\mathcal{A}'$ in the big intersection. It clearly contains the sets of the form $A \cap B$ so it suffices to check the definitions of a $\sigma$-algebra.

- You've shown $\varnothing \in T$.
- **Complement.** If $E \in T$, it is either of the form $A \cap B$ or $A \cup B^c$. Check that $E^c \in T$ in each case.
- **Countable unions.** Let $(E_n)$ be a sequence of sets in $T$.

  - If all of them are of the form $A \cap B$, say $E_n = A_n \cap B$, then $\bigcup_n E_n = (\bigcup_n A_n) \cap B \in T$.
  - If at least one of them is of the form $A \cup B^c$, then you can show that $\bigcup_n E_n = \bigcup_n (E_n \cup B^c)$. With some more work you can show that this is of the form $\tilde{A} \cup B^c$ for some $\tilde{A} \in \mathcal{A}$.

---

To prove $T \subseteq \sigma(\{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\})$ you need to show that any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}'$ containing $\{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ must also contain $T$.

Suppose $\mathcal{A}'$ contains $\{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$. It remains to show sets of the form $A \cup B^c$ are also in $\mathcal{A}'$. This is true since these are the complements of sets of the form $A^c \cap B$ which are in $\mathcal{A}'$ by assumption.